# Using Specularity effects and ColorFunction in Plot3d

Tags: plotting, color

I'd like to reproduce the 3d surface of the attached image 
[image: Surface].

What I'm interested in, is the light reflection at the basis of the surface and the rainbowlike color. 
I use Plot3d and colorfunction in order to color the surface in function of the height. However the specularity does not seem to work, i.e. it works only when one uses just a single color to paint the surface.

I looked for a solution several hours and the only thing I was able to find is this [old link](http://members.wolfram.com/jeffb/visualization/3dsurf.shtml) for something similar made in M5.2, which I'm not able to run in M9 because of obsolete functions.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Wign

Comment: Can you give example code so that we have something to start from?

Comment: Sure, here my code: `Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.65 (1 - z)]], Mesh -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 50, Lighting -> "Neutral"]`

Answer (score 5):

You can add [`Specularity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Specularity.html) to the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html).  Here is a `Manipulate` you can play with to figure out what settings you prefer:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None, Mesh -> None,
  ColorFunction -> (Directive[Specularity[s, 20], 
      Glow @ ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#3]] &),  
  Lighting -> {{"Spot", White, Scaled[{r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], r Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ],
        r Cos[θ]}], α}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], 
  {s, 0, 1}, 
 {r, 1, 4}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi/2}, {α, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm playing right now to find the proper combination :) Thank you again!

Comment: Does this still work in Mathematica 11.3 and newer? For me the specularity is not visible

Comment: @MrPuh I think you might have to wrap the Plot3D in `Style[Plot3D[...], 
 "RenderingOptions" -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]`.  I am not sure what had been changed in 11.3, but I would report it to support@wolfram.com anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from this `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[
  Exp[-x^2 - y^2],
  {x, -3, 3},
  {y, -3, 3},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  Mesh -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  Boxed -> False,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  ViewPoint -> 100 {-2, -2, 3}
]
```

let me address the question of how to use both `ColorFunction` and `Specularity` at the same time.

The key to this is the following sentence in the documentation of `ColorFunction`:

> The function specified by ColorFunction must return color directives such as RGBColor and Hue or named colors such as Red and Blue.

Supplying this function to `ColorFunction` will turn the plot red:

```
ColorFunction -> (Red &)
```

Adding `Specularity` (`White` is too harsh so I choose 60% white):

```
ColorFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[0.6], 10], Red} &)
```

Using an actual colour function instead of a single colour:

```
ColorFunction -> ({Specularity[GrayLevel[0.6], 10], Hue[.65 (1 - #3)]} &)
```

[image: Plot3D with Hue and Specularity]

As we can't just modify the default lighting angle, changing `ViewPoint` will alter where the reflection is with respect to the plot surface. (For example, try `ViewPoint -> {-2, -2, 1}`, which is closer to that in the figure you provide, but then the reflection is no longer at the base.) You will have to experiment with `Lighting` to create from scratch the lighting condition that gives you the reflection where you want for a particular `ViewPoint`.

Comment: Thank, you! I'm going to try this also: I've read that line too but I didn't find the correct way to implement and I wonder why Mathematica people didn't think to put an example. Really thanks again!

Comment: How is it possible to add opacity into this instead?

Comment: How about something like `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[0.5, Red] &)`?

Comment: or replace the `Hue[...]` above with for example `Opacity[1/2, Hue[.65 (1 - #3)]]`