# How to properly set ColorFunction and Specularity in ReliefPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have two questions about [`ReliefPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReliefPlot.html):

- How can I set the `Specularity` without changing `ColorFunction` (leaving it as `None`)?
- `ReliefPlot` doesn't seem to honor the `Specularity` at all, what I am doing wrong?

For the second question look at this example

```
n = 0.01;
t = Table[Sin[i^2 - j^2], {i, -4, 4, n}, {j, -4, 4, n}];
r1 = ReliefPlot[t, 
   ColorFunction -> ({Specularity[White, 1], Hue[0.5, 1, 1]} &), 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.7}, LightingAngle -> {Pi/6, Pi/3}];
r2 = ReliefPlot[t, 
   ColorFunction -> ({Specularity[White, 100], Hue[0.5, 1, 1]} &), 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.7}, LightingAngle -> {Pi/6, Pi/3}];
r3 = ImageData@r1 - ImageData@r2;
{r1, r2, Image[r3]}
```

this is the output

[image]

as you can see `r1` and `r2` are the same. I am using *Mathematica 10.3*

Comment: The documentation says that `Specularity` is a directive for `Graphics3D` objects, which `ReliefPlot` is not.  What kind of effect are you going for?  `LightingAngle` is an option for `ReliefPlot`, but I don't see that lighting brightness or color are.

Comment: Something like this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78281/using-specularity-effects-and-colorfunction-in-plot3d but with a 2d image in order to simulate height. Does ReliefImage allows for that?

Comment: You can play around with `ListPlot3D[t,ViewPoint->{0,0,Infinity},Lighting->...,ColorFunction->...]`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans thank you for the suggestion but `ListPlot3D` is too slow even for a small image like that. I need something that can work on images rather than real 3d plots.